# How can I cut an edge at the mathematical middle?

Tags: vertices, edges, knife-tool

I have an edge selected and I need to add a new point that is exactly at the middle of that edge.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: ? ctrl R create a vertice at the exact middle

Comment: ? edge select.. W  menu > Subdivide ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Subdivide the edge

Subdivide the edge by clicking `Subdivide` on the `Tools Panel` (<kbd>T</kbd> key) or by searching the `Subdivide` operator in the `Operator Search` (<kbd>space</kbd> key)

[image: subdivide an edge in 2]

## The edge is cut in 2

Now the edge is cut in 2 by its middle - a new vertex is added.

[image: edge cut in 2 by its middle]

## How to have more cuts?

If you want to have more vertices equally distributed, simply change the `Number of Cuts` in the `Subdivide properties`

[image: how to add 5 vertices on an edge]